# Why don't you just come like that; go out like that

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

My mom was in a hurry, she had to go somewhere with dad. But dad didn't get changed. But he didn't have to get out of the car, it was my mom who had to get out of the car, to get that work done. So she says:

> You'll just stay in the car, so just **come like that** (that is: don't get changed and just come with me in whatever you're wearing)

So is the use of "like that" natural in this context?

And if someone is ready to go out but the clothes that he/she is wearing are very tacky and the other person comments:

> Hey! You can go out **like this/that**?

What should be used "that" or "this" (if of course "like" sounds natural in this context....)

Comment: Please put a space after a comma, and before an open parenthesis (see my edit).

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence

> You'll just stay in the car, so just come **like that**.

is better as (and avoiding using "just" twice)

> You'll stay in the car, so just come **as you are**.

The second sentence

> Hey! You can go out **like this/that**?

is better as

> Hey! You can't go out **looking like that**.

Comment: So the first sentence is wrong???@Weather Vane

Comment: It is not wrong, but you asked if it is natural.

Comment: I think the *looking* is optional in your last example sentence.

Comment: Ok. So it won't be used and your alternative bis actually what would be used..... Thank you:)@Weather Vane

Comment: It might be used, but again, you asked about the sentences being "natural", and I have tried to phrase them more idiomatically.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish It could easily be used. As said, it's not wrong. I've heard it used before myself, and it's easily understandable. In fact, my *personal* opinion would be to use it rather than the suggested replacement. (Assuming there is an understood context for it. *"Do you want me to put on different clothes?" "No, just come like that."*) But there's nothing wrong with the suggested replacement either. Which you use is simply a matter of what sounds more natural *to you*. In this case, there is no objective answer.

Comment: And what about :"You have to stay in the car, so just dress like that" or " You have to stay in the car, so just dress as you are". Is "dress" a more common alternative than "come" and do these sentences mean the same as: "You just have to stay in the car, so just wear what you're wearing", @Jason Bassford.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish the person is already dressed, so "dress as you are" isn't right, but you can say "come dressed as you are".

Comment: And last question... Is "like that" used for the person standing right next to us or at a distance? Like a person is standing next to a person and says:"You can't go out like this" or "Hey! Just come out with me like this". So in both the cases the person is standing next to the person who he's talking to. So will "that" be used here or "this" will be used in this case, while pointing at the person too.

Comment: If you want indicate someone else you can see "dress like him".

Comment: No but what about the sentences in the reply above? If a person is standing next to us,will "like that" still be used? "You can't go out like this" or "Hey! Just come out with me like this". In both of these sentences the person is standing next to the person whom he's talking to.(no comparison, plain comment) So will "like that" still be used or will it be "like this"?

Comment: What do you think about my reply above @Weather Vane